# Bash sort command numeric sort, fields and dictionary sort

Tags: bash, sort

Can you explain `sort +0nr -2 +2d` please? This example is from https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html The comment says:

```
# numeric sort - biggest numbers first
# sort fields 0 and 1 first (sort starts with 0)
# followed by dictionary sort on fields 2 + 3
```

Please explain every argument used.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK that syntax is obsolete - see for example [Error “sort: cannot read: +1: no such file or directory”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486729/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver yeh but can you explain what they mean anyway?

Comment: Read `man sort` and `info sort`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an obsolete (or at least obsolescent) "traditional" syntax for specifying field and column values, documented in `info sort`:

> ```
>    On systems not conforming to POSIX 1003.1-2001, ‘sort’ supports a
> traditional origin-zero syntax ‘+POS1 [-POS2]’ for specifying sort keys.
> The traditional command ‘sort +A.X -B.Y’ is equivalent to ‘sort -k
> A+1.X+1,B’ if Y is ‘0’ or absent, otherwise it is equivalent to ‘sort -k
> A+1.X+1,B+1.Y’.
> ```

In the example you quote:

```
sort +0nr -2 +2d
```

there are two sets of specifiers: "`+0 -2`" and "`-2`". The first has `A=0`, `B=2`, `Y` absent and hence is equivalent to `-k0+1,2` i.e. `-k1,2` in in the modern 1-based indexing. The second has `A=2` with both `B` and `Y` absent so becomes just `-k3`.

Letter options have their usual meanings i.e.

```
   -d, --dictionary-order
          consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters

   -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value

   -r, --reverse
          reverse the result of comparisons
```

so the result is reverse numeric sort on the first two fields, `-k1,2nr` followed by dictionary sort on the third (and following) fields `-k3d`.

The `info` page advises against using this form of syntax:

> ```
>    Scripts intended for use on standard hosts should avoid traditional
> syntax and should use ‘-k’ instead.  For example, avoid ‘sort +2’, since
> it might be interpreted as either ‘sort ./+2’ or ‘sort -k 3’.  If your
> script must also run on hosts that support only the traditional syntax,
> it can use a test like ‘if sort -k 1 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1; then
> ...’ to decide which syntax to use.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

it is the same as `sort -k1,2nr -k3d`.